# Counting nested field sets in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

Is there a way to count the number of nested fields that have been added to a form, in Rails?

I currently have a form that allows the user to add or remove nested attributes.

The code is basically the same from the Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised just changed slightly for my requirements (different controller and model names).

What I want to be able to do is count the number of sets of nested attributes that are currently in the form. Is there a way to do this in Rails or would I be better using jQuery?

I need to be able to access the value in the view.

Any help much appreciated. If you need to see the code, let me know.

```
jQuery ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    count--
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
    $(this).closest('.panel').hide()
    $('#price').text(count)
    event.preventDefault()

  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    count++
    $('#price').text(count)
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
```

In the view I have set the count variable to 1, for testing purposes. I'm thinking that this needs to be set before the page loads as it is probably loading the javascript last, therefore not showing the initial count?

Comment: If the form adds or remove attributes on the client side, this has to be done with javascript/jquery, unless I misunderstand you.

Comment: Yes the js adds or removes the fields when a link is clicked in the view. I've placed a count variable in the on click functions to increment/decrement the value, but i now, somehow, need to access the count variable and also display it in realtime. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an element in which you want to display the count variable, say `<div id="count"></div>`, you can write `$('#count').html(count)` in the click function right after count gets updated.

UPDATE:
for the initial count (before the user clicks the add/remove button), include the count in erb page template

```
<div id="count"><%= @initial_count %></div>
```

Comment: Great this works, however, it will only display the value of count once i have clicked to add another set or remove a set. It doesn't show the first count; ie. 1.

Comment: If you know the count before the page is rendered (as you should), you can just add it to the page template.

Comment: Thanks, just updated the question. I need to move the count variable out of the view, so it gets initialised before the page loads. Thanks for all your help.